# What does the colon ( : ) mean in this javascript line?

Tags: javascript

What does the ":" mean in the 3-6th lines below?

```
function displayError(error) {
    var errorTypes = {
        0: "Unknown error",
        1: "Permission denied",
        2: "Position is not available",
        3: "Request timeout"
    };
    var errorMessage = errorTypes[error.code];
    if (error.code == 0 || error.code == 2) {
        errorMessage = errorMessage + " " + error.message;
    }
    var div = document.getElementById("location");
    div.innerHTML = errorMessage;

}
```

Comment: You may find [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) worth reading. [Chapter 4](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html) is about data structures.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The variable `errorTypes` is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers). The `:` separates the object property name (the numbers) from its value. If you are familiar with hash tables in other languages, this structure is a similar concept.  Or in PHP, for example, this could be represented as an associative array.

You can do:

```
var errorTypes = {
    0: "Unknown error",
    1: "Permission denied",
    2: "Position is not available",
    3: "Request timeout"
};

console.log(errorTypes[0]);
// Unknown error

console.log(errorTypes[2]);
// Permission denied
```

Note that the normal syntax for referencing an object property (using the dot operator) won't work for these numeric properties:

```
// Won't work for numeric properties
errorTypes.0
SyntaxError: Unexpected number

// Instead use the [] notation
errorTypes[0]
```

In this instance, since numeric property names were used, the whole thing could have been defined as an array instead and accessed exactly the same way via the `[]` notation, but with less syntactic control over the keys.

```
// As an array with the same numeric keys
var errorTypes = [
    "Unknown error",
    "Permission denied",
    "Position is not available",
    "Request timeout"
];
console.log(errorTypes[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you define key value pairs in an object. So `errorTypes.2` would return the string "Position is not available".